# Symfony 3.4 session time

Tags: symfony, php-7.1, symfony4, symfony-3.4

In my Symfony 3.4 application, the user is automatically logged out after a certain period of time. I want to change this behaviour and make my application never log out automatically. It should log out the session only when the user clicks on the logout link.

I have read the documentation and tried by setting the cookie_lifetime but it is not working for me. If anybody worked on this area please suggest how to proceed.

**Updates:**

I'm using this documentation page http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-lifetime

I'm using Symfony 3.4 flex based project.

I'm setting the configurations in config/packages/framework.yml. The configurations are as follows:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: ~
        cookie_lifetime: 31536000
        gc_maxlifetime: 31536000
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example on what you tried so far? Especially how you've set the `cookie_lifetime`? Did you use this documentation page? https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

Comment: I have added more information

Comment: Did you try out the link I provided? Seems like you also have to set up sth. in the `firewall`.

Comment: @Musterknabe Nope, remember me is not needed in this case. I have answered my own question below.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood you. You didn't want a `remember_me` function, you just wanted that the user is not getting logged out at all, correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a long debugging, I found out that the following configuration is telling Symfony to use the default PHP save handler and the default session file path.

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: ~
```

Hence Symfony session files are being stored in `/var/lib/php/sessions` directory. In Debian based operating systems, a cron job is deleting the session files every half an hour. This cron job is identifying the active sessions based on the `PIDs` associated with `apache2` and updating the last accessed time and last modification time of these active session files only.

Then the same cron job is deleting the session files which are having the last modification time before the `gc_maxlifetime` i.e; inactive sessions. The main problem is that `gc_maxlifetime` is determined based on the `php.ini` files only but not considering the Symfony's `.yaml` files. Hence the configurations in Symfony's `.yaml` files are ignored and the PHP's `gc_maxlifetime` is used.

This makes the session files being deleted after 20 minutes to 30 minutes. To fix this problem, I have updated the `.yaml` configurations as follows:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
        cookie_lifetime: 31536000
        gc_maxlifetime: 31536000
```

Now the session files are not stored inside the default `/var/lib/php/sessions` directory and hence the cron job is not deleting the session files. Now Symfony is taking care of this session handling job and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for symfony 4.

```
session:
        #handler_id: ~
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'        
        cookie_lifetime: 1800 // was "lifetime" but deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there's [RedisSessionHandler configured for session storage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/database.html#store-sessions-in-a-key-value-database-redis), one should also consider increasing the `ttl` parameter passed into the service:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
            # you can optionally pass an array of options. The only options are 'prefix' and 'ttl',
            # which define the prefix to use for the keys to avoid collision on the Redis server
            # and the expiration time for any given entry (in seconds), defaults are 'sf_s' and null:
            - { 'prefix': 'my_prefix', 'ttl': 600 } # also set equal 31536000
```